# bash script that will go through all files in a directory listed as as the first argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I need to write a bash script that will go through all the files in the directory listed as the first argument. It will print out the name and file size of any file that is less than 100 bytes long and more than 1000 bytes long.
this is what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
#

find /home/clf18ftf  -type f -size -100c -size +1000c
```

Comment: Yes, several of us can write a script to look in a specified directory and show the file name with extension and the file size, for all files which are a) <100 bytes in size, plus b)  > 1,000 bytes in size. May I ask you to click on [edit] and show us what you've written so far? There's an expectation, as per the rules here https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, you will have done some research and tried to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Sounds like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @K7AAY the problem is that i have no idea how to start as i am very new to unix

Comment: Are you trying to write a meta bash script, or is that an error in the question? (“I need to write a bash script that will write a bash script”)

Comment: Please click on [edit] to respond to the comment of the previous commentator.  Comments are for folks helping; your response would be to click [edit] and clarify or enhance your original question. Once we know if you want to write a script that writes a script, or just want to write a script to show files w/ extensions <100 bytes and >1,000 bytes in a specified directory, we can proceed.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've rolled back your edit: we can't be sure if the OP swapped the less-than/greater-than relation, or was inaccurate in using "and" (rather than "or"). Let's wait for actual clarification. (I was going to nitpick about "and"/"or" earlier, but decided against it…)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor that is an error in the question my bad ill change ir

Comment: @TheRealFawcett You're still asking for files that are "less than 100 bytes long *and* more than 1000 bytes long" *at the same time*. Such a file cannot exist. Did you mean to search for all files that are *either* < 100 B *or* > 1000 B?

Comment: @n.st Yeha thats what im looking for

Comment: Which one, @n.st described two opposing things, and you said yes that is it. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

I think `find` is your friend here. No need to write a script, just a one liner.

You will need `find «directory to search» -type f -size -100c -size +1000c`

read the find manual `man find`, and test what I have given you, there is an error in it.

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/find.html is also very useful

Comment: i tried this however it does . not work?

Comment: Yes I said there is an error in it. (though not according to the question, it finds all files that are smaller than 100 bytes and are also larger than 1000 bytes).